# How do I center a button using CSS?

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to add a button to my simple web page.  The button itself looks great, but I am not quite sure how to position it.  I would like for it to be centered and positioned below the main text.  It currently sits off to the left side.  Any idea on how to do so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spiekermann.css">
<title></title>

<style>

    #logo {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10em 0 0.2em 0;
        font-family: lato;
    }

    #sub {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: lato;
        text-align: center;
        word-spacing: 5em;
    }

    .button {
        background-color: #3b3d45;
        border: 6px solid #fff080;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .button:hover {
        background-color: #707488;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class id="logo">
    <h1>ERIK SPIEKERMANN</h1>
</div>
<div class id="sub">
    <p>Designer Typographer Entrepreneur </p>
</div>

<a href="#" class="button">Learn More</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a container. Try the following:

```
.button {
    background-color: #3b3d45;
    border: 6px solid #fff080;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 62px;
}
```

Auto margins don't apply to inline-block elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a container to the buttons and align them to center . see example below

also when you are trying to create a style . try to make them reusable as they can be. One advantage of this is you can write lesser css.

```css
#logo {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10em 0 0.2em 0;
  font-family: lato;
}

#sub {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: lato;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 5em;
}

.button {
  background-color: #3b3d45;
  border: 6px solid #fff080;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #707488;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class id="logo">
    <h1>ERIK SPIEKERMANN</h1>
</div>
<div class id="sub">
    <p>Designer Typographer Entrepreneur </p>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="#" class="button">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Button in a `<div>` and make `text-align:center`

```
<div class="btnContainer ">
    <a href="#" class="button">Learn More</a>
</div>

<style>
    .btnContainer {
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without extra markup adding the following rules to `.button` will do the trick

```
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spiekermann.css">
<title></title>

<style>

    #logo {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10em 0 0.2em 0;
        font-family: lato;
    }

    #sub {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: lato;
        text-align: center;
        word-spacing: 5em;
    }

    .button {
        background-color: #3b3d45;
        border: 6px solid #fff080;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: auto;

    }

    .button:hover {
        background-color: #707488;
    }
    #button {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class id="logo">
    <h1>ERIK SPIEKERMANN</h1>
</div>
<div class id="sub">
    <p>Designer Typographer Entrepreneur </p>
</div>
<div class id="button">
    <a href="#" class="button">Learn More</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

how do you think this way?